# mySQLi prepared statements and binding

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare

When preparing a mySQLi statement do I need to bind parameters?

```
 public function query($sql){
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($this-> connect, $sql);
    $array= array();
    $query=mysqli_query($this->connect, $sql);
    if ($query > 0){
      $c=mysqli_num_rows ($query);
      if($c > 1){
        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
        array_push($array, $fetch);
        }
      }
    return $array;
    }else ...

   exit();
}
```

the `...` is just some more conditions to follow through.  It just shows what my question is. The way I prepare is that ok or should I do this better. I've never used the prepare method and i am new to this. Also is it best practice to exit the query at the end?

Comment: If the query contains any `?` placeholders, you need to call `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` to provide the values for them.

Comment: To execute a prepared query, you use `mysql_stmt_execute()`. The second argument to `msyqli_query` is just a string, not a prepared statement.

Comment: There are lots of examples in the mysqli documentation, why don't you start there?

Comment: Ok. Yeah sorry I dont have direct internet access I'm using my mobile device. So is it still secure without using the prepare?

Comment: It depends on whether you properly escape the data with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` before inserting into the query string.

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks Barmar